# How to filter grouped ObservableCollection using Searchbar

Tags: mvvm, maui, observablecollection, collectionview

I'm trying to filter ObservableCollection hooked up to CollectionView but it is very complicated because it has complex objects and it is grouped. I was trying to follow the video on youtube but it was about just strings not grouped :( The SearchBar is hooked up to a command which sends the string to task using parameter.

```
    <SearchBar
        x:Name="searchBar"
        SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}"
        SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference searchBar}}" />
```

This is my current attempt at trying to filter that observable.

```
    async Task SearchTask(string query)
    {
        var SearchTerm = query;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchTerm))
        {
            SearchTerm = string.Empty;
        }

        SearchTerm = SearchTerm.ToLowerInvariant();

        foreach (var group in TechnicList)
        {
            var filteredItems = group
                .Where(value => value.media.Title.UserPreferred.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(SearchTerm)).ToList();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchTerm))
            {
                filteredItems = group.Entries.ToList();
            }

            foreach (var value in group)
            {

                if (!filteredItems.Contains(value))
                {
                    foreach (var VARIABLE in AnimeGroupObservable)
                    {
                        if (VARIABLE.Name == group.Name)
                        {
                            VARIABLE.Remove(value);
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (var VARIABLE in AnimeGroupObservable)
                {
                    if (VARIABLE.Name == group.Name)
                    {
                        
                        if (!VARIABLE.Contains(value))
                        {
                            group.Add(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My properties:

```
private  List<Models.Group> TechnicList;

public ObservableCollection<Models.Group> _AnimeGroupObservable;

public ObservableCollection<Models.Group> AnimeGroupObservable
{
    get => _AnimeGroupObservable;
    set
    {
        if (value == _AnimeGroupObservable)
            return;

        _AnimeGroupObservable = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

After I get whole data from API, make some operations on them so they are compatible with groups I just assign them, so they are 1:1

```
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                TechnicList = new List<Models.Group>(
                    userGroups.groups
                );

                AnimeGroupObservable = new ObservableCollection<Models.Group>(TechnicList);

                MessagingCenter.Send(AnimeGroupObservable, "AllAnimeGroups");

            });
```

And here is how my objects look, first with groups:

```
public class Group : List<ListEntry>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool isCustomList { get; set; }
    public bool isSplitCompletedList { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int entryCount { get; set; }
    public List<ListEntry> Entries { get; set; }

    public Group(string name, bool iscustomList, bool issplitCompletedList, string Status,
        List<ListEntry> entries) : base(entries)
    {
        Name = name;
        isCustomList = iscustomList;
        isSplitCompletedList = issplitCompletedList;
        status = Status;
    }
}
```

As for the ListEntry:

```
public class ListEntry : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public int? id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, bool> CustomLists { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<customListItem> CustomListsList { get; set; }
    public Media media { get; set; }
    public int? _score;

    public int? score
    {
        get => _score;
        set
        {
            if (value == _score)
                return;

            _score = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int _Progress;
    public int progress
    {
        get => _Progress;
        set
        {
            if (value == _Progress)
                return;

            _Progress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Date startedAt { get; set; }
}
```

If there is anything that can make the whole thing with better performance I'm listening. I can use any packages, toolkit or whatever. What I wanna do is to filter those grouped ListEntries by ListEntry.Media.Title.UserPreferred case-insensitive. So if I type title only those entries with those titles will appear (in groups of course). If XAML for collection view is somehow needed:

```
<RefreshView
        x:Name="HomeRefreshView"
        BackgroundColor="DodgerBlue"
        Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
        IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}"
        RefreshColor="White">
        <CollectionView
            x:Name="CollectionView1"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            IsGrouped="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding AnimeGroupObservable}"
            ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepScrollOffset"
            SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentEntry}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            VerticalOptions="Fill">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="15" Orientation="Vertical" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label
                            Margin="30,15,0,5"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="25">
                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                <FormattedString>
                                    <Span Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                    <Span Text=": " />
                                    <Span Text="{Binding entryCount}" />
                                </FormattedString>
                            </Label.FormattedText>
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame
                            Margin="15,0,15,0"
                            Padding="0"
                            BackgroundColor="#1e2529"
                            BorderColor="Transparent"
                            CornerRadius="10"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                            <Grid Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Frame
                                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Padding="0"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    CornerRadius="10">
                                    <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding media.CoverImage.Large}">
                                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.OpenMediaCommand, Source={x:Reference AnimeListPagee}}" CommandParameter="{Binding media}" />
                                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </Image>
                                </Frame>
                                <Label
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    FontSize="12"
                                    MaxLines="3"
                                    Text="{Binding media.Title.UserPreferred}"
                                    TextColor="White" />
                                <Label
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    FontSize="12"
                                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                                    TextColor="White"
                                    VerticalOptions="End">
                                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                        <FormattedString>
                                            <Span Text="Score: " />
                                            <Span Text="{Binding score}" />
                                        </FormattedString>
                                    </Label.FormattedText>
                                </Label>
                                <StackLayout
                                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    Padding="0"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    Spacing="0"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Button
                                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                        Padding="0"
                                        BackgroundColor="Crimson"
                                        Command="{Binding BindingContext.IncreaseCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=AnimeListPagee}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        CornerRadius="360"
                                        FontAutoScalingEnabled="False"
                                        FontSize="Body"
                                        HeightRequest="30"
                                        Text="+"
                                        TextColor="White"
                                        VerticalOptions="Start"
                                        WidthRequest="30" />
                                    <StackLayout
                                        Padding="0"
                                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label
                                            FontSize="12"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            Text="{Binding progress}"
                                            TextColor="White" />
                                        <BoxView
                                            Margin="5,0,5,0"
                                            HeightRequest="1"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            Color="White" />
                                        <Label
                                            FontSize="12"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            Text="{Binding media.Episodes}"
                                            TextColor="White" />
                                    </StackLayout>

                                    <Button
                                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                        Padding="0"
                                        BackgroundColor="Crimson"
                                        Command="{Binding BindingContext.DecreaseCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=AnimeListPagee}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        CornerRadius="360"
                                        FontAutoScalingEnabled="False"
                                        FontSize="Body"
                                        HeightRequest="30"
                                        IsEnabled="True"
                                        Text="-"
                                        TextColor="White"
                                        VerticalOptions="End"
                                        WidthRequest="30" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </RefreshView>
```

Comment: is there a specific problem with this code, or does it work but you want to make it faster or less complex?  It would probably be simpler to use LINQ to query the flat/ungrouped list, and then apply the grouping logic to the results of that query

Comment: No, It doesn't work at all I'm afraid. Something's wrong for sure.
Pretty much what I wanna do is to filter those groups for ListEntry.Media.Title.UserPreferred so only those items that have matching title (contains) with SearchTerm are visible in CollectionView. I've tried to do it on ungrouped lists by doing foreach (var group in TechnicList) and then do stuff on them and apply that on my Observable (AnimeGroupObservable) as you saw in my example but nope nothing visible happens and code is wrong too probably. I think I've tried LINQ too but i've failed to do so too

Comment: can you easily re-apply the grouping logic to the original data?  Or is it already grouped when you get the data from your API?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then no I cannot re-apply logic to the "original" data. The Data is taken from public API (I have no control over it), sorted (by group name), grouped and assigned to property so It's visible on the collection view. From what I see I actually used LINQ for that - https://pastebin.com/SHeNmrhU

I'm open for any ungrouping and grouping as long as it doesn't meddle with logic I already have in pastebin link. (Which it shouldn't meddle). Is it possible that we ungroup it, make logic and group it back together and put it on my Observable?

Comment: the code in that link appears to take the API data, sort it, and then group it.  So I don't understand why you could not filter the API data, sort it, and then group it again.  That is typically how you would filter a grouped collection.

Answer (score 0):

I guess dotnet Maui by default set the binding mode to One-time, You could try switching Binding Mode on Collection View to OneWay, Alternatively You can explicitly Set the Itemsource again after doing mutation on ItemSource List

```
<CollectionView
            x:Name="CollectionView1"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            IsGrouped="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding AnimeGroupObservable, Mode="OneWay"}"
            ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepScrollOffset"
            SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentEntry}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            VerticalOptions="Fill">
            </CollectionView>
```

Or

End of Search Command Method

```
CollectionView1.ItemSource = filteredItems
```

More info on binding modes
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode

Comment: The default is One-way but the whole solution is far from what I've wanted to achieve. Besides I'm using viewmodel not code-behind to even explicitly set itemsource

Comment: Also, collection view is grouped so it wouldn't accept ungrouped filteredItems

Answer (score 0):

first, start with the original data you get from the API

first, filter it

```
var filtered = APIData.Where(x => x.media.Title.UserPreferred.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(SearchTerm)).ToList();
```

then sort it

```
var sorted = // sort logic
```

then group it

```
var grouped = // group logic
```

then assign it back to your `ItemsSource`

Comment: But the original refresh logic that i have in pastebin can be left untouched? The original data would be assigned to a separate property for filtering purposes in a filtering command.

Or do you want me to download data each time that I want to filter?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting it done cause the data looks really different from what you've written. Necessary parts - https://pastebin.com/KCvMsbT5

                    var filtered = graphQlResponseAnimeList.Data.MediaListCollection.lists.Where(x =>
                        x.entries.Where(y => y.media.Title.UserPreferred.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(query)).ToList());

Comment: "data looks really different" - I have no idea what this means.  What **specific** problem are you having?  What **specifically** looks different?  What is the type of `Data.MediaListCollection.lists`?

Comment: `public List<List> lists { get; set; }` as for the List it's in pastebin but I managed to do this:
                   ` var filtered = graphQlResponseAnimeList.Data.MediaListCollection.lists;

                    foreach (var x in filtered)
                    {
                        x.entries = x.entries.Where(x => x.media.Title.UserPreferred.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(query))
                            .ToList();
                    }`
Thats works but I'm also facing issue that command won't trigger if searchbar text is empty. It won't pass empty string  as parameter

Comment: I might use event instead or something as I also need to somehow enable user to clear filtering to display full list again

Comment: Searchbar has a built in cancel button

Comment: It does but I don't see any command for it or an event to do the logic for cancellation. At least I don't see anything in docs
Right now I have SearchCommand which is hooked up to a Command which passes the parameter to a Task.

Comment: Issue I'm facing with this is that doing those operations affect "APIData"

https://pastebin.com/h9hWvq9x - my data is "apiListData" of type GraphQlResponse<Data> (Data is my type of course) by the end of the code it is already affected which is not good. I could have it serialized to json string and deserialized when needed but this is not fast especially if I'd like to have remotely good experience of filtering on each key stroke. I tried to avoid it by making another local variable as you see in pastebin but it all leads to one object and modifies it.

Comment: code you need help with needs to be posted in the body of your question and properly formatted, not linked as an off-site resource